# como fazer com que a minha função retorne a incrementação?

Tags: javascript, react

é o seguinte estou com um dificuldade de encontrar onde está o erro desse código, eu quero fazer um contador, porém toda vez está dizendo que o setCounter não e uma função.

```
import React, {useState}from 'react';
//componente: e um bloco isolado de HTML, CSS e JS, o qual não interfere no resto da aplicação
// propriedade: informaçoes que um componete PAI passa para um componente filho.
// Estado:



//pro exemplo o app e um componente 
function App() {
  //bom aqui foi criado uma variavel counter que vai pegar o useState que vai comecar com o valor 0.
  const {counter, setCounter} = useState(0);
  function incrementCounter(){
      setCounter(counter + 1);
      }
  return(
    <>
      <h1>Contador: {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>incrementar</button>
    </>
  )

}

export default App;
```

help me please!

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando o desestruturador errado. Chaves `{}` servem para desestruturar um objeto, colchetes `[]` server para desestruturar um array.

O retorno da função `useState` é uma array com dois itens, o primeiro item representa o seu estado, e o segundo é o método para mutar o seu estado. Logo, para armazenar esses dois itens em variáveis, você deveria estar utilizando `const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)`.

---

Outro detalhe para o código: a função `setCounter` não irá mutar o seu estado imediatamente após ser invocada, não há garantia de que o valor de `counter` ainda será o mesmo que era quando você invocou `setCounter`, o que pode gerar uma inconsistência. Quando você precisa mutar o seu estado com base num valor anterior, você deve utilizar callbacks, ao invés de

```
setCounter(counter + 1)
```

Utilize

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1)
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo.